# Tweet is not sending from my real device

Tags: ios, twitter

I have an app which build on Xcode using Objective-C. Users can send tweet, when I try to send from my iPhone it says (Can not Send Tweet, because the connection to Twitter failed). It is working with the simulator, her is the code I use:

```
if ([SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter])
        {


NSString *tweetBody = self.currentList.tweetBody;
NSString *rawStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", tweetBody];


SLComposeViewController *composeController = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter];

[composeController setInitialText:rawStr];
[composeController addURL: [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://my app url on Apple store"]];

[self presentViewController:composeController
                               animated:YES completion:nil];

SLComposeViewControllerCompletionHandler myBlock = ^(SLComposeViewControllerResult result){
if (result == SLComposeViewControllerResultCancelled) {

NSLog(@"delete");

} else

{
NSLog(@"post");
}

};
composeController.completionHandler =myBlock;
}

}];
```

I hope to find the answer with you guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you checked the Privacy settings for Twitter? It's possible that you didn't grant it permission to access your Twitter accounts. The image below shows all apps that have been granted permission to access my Twitter account,

[image: The Twitter Privacy settings.]

Comment: Does your app show in the Twitter permissions list?

Comment: Ok, have you set up a Twitter account on the device? If not then if ([SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter]) will not evaluate and the rest of your code won't run.

Comment: Yes i did set a Twitter account!

Comment: Try deleting your app and reinstalling it. If that doesn't help log out and back into your Twitter account.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74513/discussion-between-dlanmaar-and-ahmed-s-alkaabi).

Comment: sorry about yesterday, I missed my connection from my mobile. Can I continue with you to solve my problem.